# Processor Pipeline Specifications?

Tags: cpu, specifications

Was just wondering if there exists a place where you can find pipelining specifications for specific processors (tells how many stages and a description of the stages) I have been searching for a while now on google and have not been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that Tom's Hardware usually has good articles on new microarchitectures that are detailed without being overly technical.
[Here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel,264-8.html) is a page from their Pentium 4 article with details on the pipeline.